# Get All IDs Starting With "x"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an output of elements on a page with this:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
ExportIds = $('[id^="appendHeading"]').attr('id');
ExportTexts = $('[id^="appendHeading"]').text();
$("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:"+ExportIds+"Content:"+ExportTexts);
});
```

But It only gets the "last ID" but not all of them. I've been to this trouble before and needs to get it in my head!

I want the output to be "ObjectID:appendHeading,Content:Texts,ObjectID:appendHeading,Content:Texts" etc.,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always cache jQuery objects with slow selectors in a variable if you are going to use them more than once. So I cached it in a variable called `$els`. Then I made an adjustment since [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) only returns the attribute for the first matched element, and [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns a string not an array of strings. I use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create a jQuery object containing the values you want, and then I use [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert that jQuery object to an array:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
    var $els = $('[id^="appendHeading"]');
    ExportIds = $els.map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    ExportTexts = $els.map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:"+ExportIds+"Content:"+ExportTexts);
});
```

If you are trying to output each id, text pair rather than all the ids followed by all the text, you may want to rewrite it further like this:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
    var textMap = {};
    $('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function(){
        textMap[this.id] = $(this).text();
    });
    for(id in textMap)
        $("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:" + id + "Content:" + textMap[id]);
});
```

Or even:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
    $('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function(){
        $("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:" + this.id + "Content:" + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a great explanation! And that you took your time! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need something like this:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click', function () {
  $('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function () {
    $("#PrintIds").append('ObjectID: ' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Content: ' + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use each().

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
  var PrintIds = $('#PrintIds');
  $('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function() {
    PrintIds.append('ObjectID:'+$(this).attr('id')+'Content:'+$(this).text());
  });
});
```